# Unit Test for two classes inherit an Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I have two classes that implement an interface, but both classes have a parameter passed into the constructor to identify what class the application would need. I am trying to test one (GetAvailablity) method on (AvailablityRepoData) class when I create an instance of AvailablityRepoData I am getting an error for non-virtual method. I would really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

```
public interface IAvailablityRepo
   {
     string  GetAvailablity(Availablity availablity);
}
public class AvailablityRepoData: IAvailablityRepo
{

    public AvailablityRepoData(string websetting) {
    }
    public string GetAvailablity(Availablity availablity) {
        return "Data";
    }
}

public class AvailablityRepoWeb:IAvailablityRepo
{
    public AvailablityRepoWeb(string DataSetting) {
    }
    public string GetAvailablity(Availablity availablity) {
        return "Web";
    }
}

public class Availablity
{
    public virtual string Id {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual string  Status {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

        var a = new Availablity() { Id = "111", Status = "A"};
        Mock<IAvailablityRepo> mockRepo = new Mock<IAvailablityRepo>();
        Mock<IAvailablityRepo> RepoData = new Mock<IAvailablityRepo>();
        RepoData.Setup(x => x.GetAvailablity(It.IsAny<Availablity>  ())).Returns("pass");
        var result = RepoData.Object.GetAvailablity(a);
```

Comment: Please format your code propperly.

Comment: What is the exact error?  Also, is it a run-time error or a compile-time error?

Comment: run time error i dont want to make Get GetAvailablity virtual method on AvailablityRepoData

Comment: Could you add the entire error message? From your code snippet it's not immediately clear what's going wrong.

Comment: As a sidenote: the test is currently just testing whether Moq works as expected. You are providing a fake implementation of GetAvailablility and are directly checking whether this fake implementation returns a correct response. This test is not testing a single line of production code.

Comment: What are you trying to test ?

Comment: I am trying to test a logic that invlove GetAvailablity method on AvailablityRepoData , when im setting up the mock for ( AvailablityRepoData ) im getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been said in the comments, it's not clear from the code you've posted what your error is.  If I copy and past it straight into visual studio (wrapping the test code in a test), the test passes fine.  I'm going to suggest that when you experienced the error, you test code was actually closer to this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    var a = new Availablity() { Id = "111", Status = "A" };
    Mock<IAvailablityRepo> mockRepo = new Mock<IAvailablityRepo>();
    Mock<AvailablityRepoData> RepoData = new Mock<AvailablityRepoData>();
    RepoData.Setup(x => x.GetAvailablity(It.IsAny<Availablity>())).Returns("pass");
    var result = RepoData.Object.GetAvailablity(a);
}
```

This results in an error when the test is run:

```
System.NotSupportedException:Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member:
                             x => x.GetAvailablity(It.IsAny<Availablity>())
```

The difference between this test and your original test is that I've changed the Mocked type from the interface `IAvailabilityRepo` to `AvailabilityRepoData` which is the concrete class.  Since Moq only supports mocking of interfaces / virtual methods it's naturally getting upset.

As has been mentioned by @prgmtc, your test as it stands doesn't really testing much of anything.

With your current code, it doesn't actually look like you need to be using Mocks at all.  Something like this might be a more appropriate test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDataRepoReturnsDataAvailability() {
    var someImportantSetting = "thisShouldBeSomethingMeaningful";
    var availability = new Availablity() { Id = "111", Status = "A" };
    var sut = new AvailablityRepoData(someImportantSetting);

    var returnedAvailability = sut.GetAvailablity(availability);

    Assert.AreEqual("Data", returnedAvailability);
}
```

Assuming your actual code is more complex the string passed into your data repo would presumably need to be rather more meaningful...

As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't be mocking the system under test.  If you find yourself creating a mock for the system you're testing it's a good indication that you've got to much functionality in one class and/or you're trying to test the wrong thing...

As an asside, you may want to look into something like the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create your different repos rather than passing the type into the constructor for each of the repos as you seem to be suggesting.